# Proving if L2 converges, then L1 as well.

Tags: integration, normed-spaces

I would like to know how to prove that since having $$ \left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)_{n}-f(x)|^2 dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \rightarrow 0 $$ when  $n \rightarrow\infty  $. Then we have that $$ \left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)_{n}-f(x)| dx\right) \rightarrow 0$$
also when $n \rightarrow\infty  $.
How may I solve this just by bounding the $L1$ distance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b}|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|dx\leq\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|^{2}dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{a}^{b}1^{2}dx\right)^{1/2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: (By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality)